# Dropdown Menu with For Loop: How to Implement Automatic Closing of Other Dropdowns on Click

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

My menu is not working as I want. I usually can write only the menu with a for loop, but it doesn't work like it should. If one item of menu is clicked it remains open until I click it again. The menu that I can write shows content when I click on it, but the other dropdowns do not close automatically when I click on another item in the menu. How can I change my code to solve the problem and obtain automatic closing of other dropdowns each time I click the next menu item?

```js
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
const menucontent = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const subTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-title');
const subItem = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-item');
for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
menu[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
menucontent[i].classList.toggle('show');
menu[i].classList.toggle('darkgrey');
});

window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(!e.target.matches('.menu') && !e.target.matches('.item') && !e.target.matches('.sub-title') && !e.target.matches('.fas')){menu[i].classList.remove('darkgrey');
menucontent[i].classList.remove('show');
}
else if(e.target.matches('.sub-title') || e.target.matches('.fas')){
subItem[0].classList.toggle('present');
subTitle[0].classList.toggle('clear');
menu[0].classList.toggle('darkgrey');
menucontent[0].classList.toggle('show');
}
})
}
```

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:rgb(128,128,128);
}
*{
    font-family: 'Georama', sans-serif;
}
.menu-bar{
    position:fixed;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    
}
.menu-bar .menu{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-right:40px;
    padding:25px 25px 50px 25px;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:900;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select:none;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    
    
    
    
}
.menu-bar .menu:hover:nth-of-type(1)::before{
position:absolute;
content:'';
width:25px;
height:25px;
background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(128,128,128);
top: 39px;
left:-25px;
border-radius:30px;
z-index:-1;
}
.menu-bar .menu:hover:nth-of-type(1)::after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(128,128,128);
    top:39px;
    left:100%;
    border-radius:30px;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    z-index:-1;
}



.menu-bar .menu:hover:nth-of-type(2)::before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(128,128,128);
    top: 39px;
    left:-25px;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:-1;
    }
    .menu-bar .menu:hover:nth-of-type(2)::after{
        position:absolute;
        content:'';
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(128,128,128);
        top:39px;
        left:100%;
        border-radius:30px;
        transform:rotate(90deg);
        z-index:-1;
        
    }







.menu-bar .menu:hover:nth-of-type(3)::before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(128,128,128);
    top: 39px;
    left:-25px;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:-1;
    }
    .menu-bar .menu:hover:nth-of-type(3)::after{
        position:absolute;
        content:'';
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(128,128,128);
        top:39px;
        left:100%;
        border-radius:30px;
        transform:rotate(90deg);
        z-index:-1;
    }


.menu:hover{
    background-color:rgb(128,128,128);
   
    
}
.item{
  
    display:none;}
    
 .sub-item{
   display:none
}
.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(1) .item.show{
    position:absolute;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color:rgb(24, 24, 227);
    width: 180px;
    z-index:2;
    top:65%;
    left:-40px; 
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    
    
}


.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(2) .item.show{
    position:absolute;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color:rgb(24, 24, 227);
    width: 180px;
    z-index:2;
    top:65%;
    left:-30px; 
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    
    
}



.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(3) .item.show{
    position:absolute;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color:rgb(24, 24, 227);
    width: 180px;
    z-index:2;
    top:65%;
    left:-25px; 
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
   
    
}

.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(1) .item.show::before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(24, 24, 227);
    top: -25px;
    left:15px;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(1) .item.show::after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: -10px 10px 0px rgb(24, 24, 227);
    top: -25px;
    left:135px;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:-1;
    
}



.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(2) .item.show::before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(24, 24, 227);
    top: -25px;
    left:5px;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(2) .item.show::after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: -10px 10px 0px rgb(24, 24, 227);
    top: -25px;
    left:154px;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:-1;
    
}





.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(3) .item.show::before {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(24, 24, 227);
    top: -25px;
    left:0%;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.menu-bar .menu:nth-of-type(3) .item.show::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgb(24, 24, 227);
    top: -25px;
    left:152px;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:-1;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}



.item a{
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    


}
.item .sub-title {
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 30px;
    background-color: brown;
    border-radius: 0 0 19px 19px;
}
.item a:hover, .sub-title:hover{background-color:green;
    color:white;
animation:alter 4.5s infinite;


}



@keyframes alter{
    0%{filter:hue-rotate(0deg)}
    100%{filter:hue-rotate(360deg)}
}

.sub-title:hover{
    border-radius: 0 0 19px 19px;}
.item a:hover:last-child{
    border-radius: 0 0 19px 19px;
}
.menu.darkgrey{
    
    background-color:rgb(24, 24, 227);
   
}


.hide{display:none;}

.present{display:block;}
.sub-title.clear{
    border-radius:0px;
}
.fas{
    color:black;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left:15px;
    transition-duration:0.2s;
}
.sub-title.clear .fas{
    
    transform:rotateZ(180deg);
    transition-duration:0.2s;
}
.sub-item{
    background-color:rgb(98, 98, 189);
    border-radius:0 0 20px 20px;
    
}
.sub-title:hover .fas{
    color:white;

    
}
```

```html
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Georama:wght@500&family=Montserrat&family=Oxygen:wght@300&family=Quicksand:wght@600;700&family=Righteous&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/df3ec16d5b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="menu">Work
    <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Programming</a>
    <a href="#">Cybersecurity</a>
    <div class ="sub-title">Networking<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
      <div class="sub-item">
        <a href="#">Cisco</a>
        <a href="#">Microsoft</a>
        <a href="#">Oracle</a>
</div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="menu">Services
    <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Web developping</a>
    <a href="#">Codding</a>
    <a href="#">Other services</a>
    </div></div>
    <div class="menu">Learning
      <div class="item">
      <a href="#">C++</a>
      <a href="#">Phyton</a>
      <a href="#">Javascript</a>
      </div></div>
    </div>
```

I was trying to use forEach loop, querySelector, and querySelectorAll options but it fails for now.

Comment: Please give your question a title that describes the specific problem. Your title describes 90% of the questions on the site.

Comment: You're adding multiple event listeners on the `window`, they'll all run when you click. The `if` conditions are not specific to `menu[i]`, so all of them will be either true or false at the same time, and they'll toggle all the menu items.

Comment: Just add a single window event listener. It should figure out which item you've clicked on, then toggle the corresponding menu item.

Comment: Please add your HTML  code as well so it is easy to test your code on our end.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to keep track of the currently open dropdown and close it when a new menu item is clicked. See the modified code and read the comment to understand how I solved your issue. I hope It will be useful for you.

```
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
const menucontent = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const subTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-title');
const subItem = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-item');
let openIndex = -1; // Variable to keep track of the currently open dropdown

for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
  menu[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const isSubmenu = e.target.matches('.sub-title') || e.target.matches('.fas');

    if (isSubmenu) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the click event from reaching the window listener
      subItem[i].classList.toggle('present');
      subTitle[i].classList.toggle('clear');
    } else {
      if (openIndex !== -1 && openIndex !== i) {
        menucontent[openIndex].classList.remove('show');
        menu[openIndex].classList.remove('darkgrey');
      }

      menucontent[i].classList.toggle('show');
      menu[i].classList.toggle('darkgrey');
      openIndex = (openIndex === i) ? -1 : i;
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (
      !e.target.matches('.menu') &&
      !e.target.matches('.item') &&
      !e.target.matches('.sub-title') &&
      !e.target.matches('.fas')
    ) {
      if (openIndex !== -1) {
        menucontent[openIndex].classList.remove('show');
        menu[openIndex].classList.remove('darkgrey');
        openIndex = -1;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have added link to html

Comment: @SzymonHoworus I have tested my javascript code on your codepen, it works please check it and confirm

Comment: As I want but submenu is not working yet.

Comment: @SzymonHoworus Answer updated please check it

Comment: Yes, now is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is working too.